# Using JavaScript to add new row to table but how to I set the variables to be unique if I clone?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that the user clicks on to add a new row to the bottom of an input table. I would like this to also increment the id. So the next row would have desc2, hours2, rate2 and amount2 as the id. Is there a way to do this in the JavaScript function.

Also - just want to check my logic on this. After the user completes the filled out form, I will be writing all the data to a mysql database on two different tables. Is this the best way to go about this? I want the user to be able to add as many lines in the desc_table as they need. If this is the correct way to be going about this, what is the best way to determine how many lines they have added so I can insert into the db table using a while loop?

JS file:

```
function new_line() {
    var t = document.getElementById("desc_table");
    var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
    var x = rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    x.style.display = "";
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(x, r);
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="desc_table">
        <tr>
            <td><font><br><h3>Description</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Hours</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Rate</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Amount</h3></font></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><textarea name="description" id="desc1" ></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="hours" id="hours1" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="rate" id="rate1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount1"></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="add_btn" onclick="new_line(this)">+</button>
                <button type="button" name="delete_btn" onclick="delete_row(this)">x</button>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you need those ids for?  I would recommend not using them at all.

Comment: Do you want unique IDs or just increment?
And why would you insert into DB with a while loop?

Comment: I am fairly new to this so please steer me in the right direction. What I need the IDs for: Don't I need to uniquely identify each line in order to enter it in the table? Yes I believe a unique ID is best for this. At the top of the page, I was going to do an isset for the save button. But then I wasn't sure how to grab all the description information if I don't know how many lines the user has added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code.After appending the row it counts the number of rows and and then assigns via if condition and incremental procedure the id's:

```js
 function new_line() {
    var t = document.getElementById("desc_table");
    var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
    var x = rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    x.style.display = "";
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(x, r);
   
    for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++){
       
        if(rows[i].children["0"].children["0"].id.match((/desc/g))){
           rows[i].children["0"].children["0"].id='desc'+i; 
        }
        if(rows[i].children["1"].children["0"].id.match((/hours/g))){
           rows[i].children["1"].children["0"].id='hours'+i; 
        }
        if(rows[i].children["2"].children["0"].id.match((/rate/g))){
           rows[i].children["2"].children["0"].id='rate'+i; 
        }
        if(rows[i].children["3"].children["0"].id.match((/amount/g))){
           rows[i].children["3"].children["0"].id='amount'+i; 
        }
    }
   }
```

```html
<table id="desc_table">
        <tr>
            <td><font><br><h3>Description</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Hours</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Rate</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Amount</h3></font></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><textarea name="description" id="desc1" ></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="hours" id="hours1" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="rate" id="rate1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount1"></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="add_btn" onclick="new_line(this)">+</button>
                <button type="button" name="delete_btn" onclick="delete_row(this)">x</button>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change variable names for more descriptive. :)

Example solution...
https://jsfiddle.net/Platonow/07ckv5u7/1/

```
function new_line() {
    var table = document.getElementById("desc_table");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var row = rows[rows.length - 1];
    var newRow = rows[rows.length - 1].cloneNode(true);

    var inputs = newRow.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(let i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].id = inputs[i].name + rows.length;
    }

    var textarea = newRow.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
    textarea.id = textarea.name + rows.length;

    table.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

Note that I removed/edited below fragment.

```
x.style.display = "";
r.parentNode.insertBefore(x, r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a lot easier with jquery or another dom manipulation language, but with vanilla JS here's an example of simply looping through the new row's inputs & textarea and incrementing a counter to append.

```js
var count = 1;

function new_line() {
    count++;
    
    var t = document.getElementById("desc_table");
    var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
    var x = rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    x.style.display = "";
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(x, r);
    
    // update input ids
    var newInputs = Array.from(x.getElementsByTagName('input'))
            .concat(Array.from(x.getElementsByTagName('textarea')));
    newInputs.forEach(function(input) {
        var id = input.getAttribute('id').replace(/[0-9].*/, '');
        input.setAttribute('id', id + count);
    });
}
```

```html
<table id="desc_table">
        <tr>
            <td><font><br><h3>Description</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Hours</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Rate</h3></font></td>
            <td><font><h3>Amount</h3></font></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><textarea name="description" id="desc1" ></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="hours" id="hours1" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="rate" id="rate1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount1"></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="add_btn" onclick="new_line(this)">+</button>
                <button type="button" name="delete_btn" onclick="delete_row(this)">x</button>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
```

Comment: The id's  doesn't have an ascending or descending logic

Comment: @liontass he's using insertBefore, so the new row appends before the last row instead of after. I don't know why, so I left it. Odds are the order doesn't matter anyway

Comment: I tried the code you supplied. sorry - it was probably my mistake but I just couldn't get it to work the way I needed. Thank you though.